# How to simulate hardware to measure .net application performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, testing, profiling

I am trying to optimize my application performance which is written by C# to do I am trying to get measurements for some functionality of my system such as (Throughput, Resource utilization, Workload, execution time, Garbage collections, etc) to measure theses stuffs I am using some type of Profilers and performance monitors.

I can see these tools are giving different results for different hardware configurations. So I want to limit my hardware configuration for minimum requirement.My problems are

- How to limit hardware resources(Such as CPU,Memory
  ,Storage) virtually (by some kind of simulators)?
- Are there any tool exist for these kind of
  testing (Open Source is best?
- If I am doing wrong, can any one suggest what is the professional approach to do these
  testing?

Comment: You're describing "load testing."

Comment: Have you considered testing your application in a virtual machine? This would give you lots of options regarding CPU usage and amount of memory available.

Comment: @StfanM not yet but.i am wondering some time my tools will get stuck if i use virtual machines.But i will try it first and update here if i get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

> If i am doing wrong, can any one suggest what is the professional approach to do these testing?

The best "professional" approach, and the only truly accurate measure, is to build a machine with your minimum specs and test there.  Any simulation will only be an approximation *at best* of a real system with those specifications.

That being said, many VM solutions allow you to change the resource allocation to a specific VM, which can help simulate reduced resource availability.  For example, [VMWare lets you allocate the number of processors](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-9745D560-9243-4262-A585-D709D52B1349.html), max memory, disk space, etc.

Comment: Thanks..I would try the VMWare first then i will update comments